# performance analysis for boost::bind compare to for loop

Tags: c++, boost

I converted

```
  for(std::set<shape::Face>::iterator face_iter=vec_face.begin(); face_iter!=vec_face.end(); face_iter++)
   {
     hiddenCorner(other, bmap, *face_iter);
   }
```

into

```
for_each(vec_face.begin(), vec_face.end(), boost::bind(hiddenCorner, other, bmap, _1));
```

Obviously it is less verbose, but how about efficiency?

hiddenCorner is a void function which update bmap (bmap is a std::map).

**NOTE**: vec_face is not a really big size set.

Comment: why not measure it and find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> hiddenCorner is a void function which update bmap (bmap is a std::map).

The `bind` version makes copies of `other` and `bmap` which are stored in the binder, *then* passes them to the function, so the function updates the copy in the binder, not `bmap` itself.

So apparently not only have you not tried to measure performance yourself, you haven't even tested to see if it works. No cookie for you.

If you write it properly, using `boost::ref`, it should be roughly equivalent performance, assuming you turn on optimisation.